# Efficient method to determine video encoding of upload to Azure Blob in ASP .Net Core 2

Tags: video, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, quicktime, azure-media-services

Our SPA uploads cell phone videos. Newer iPhones upload videos in `.Mov` container with `H.265` under some circumstances which chrome doesn't play natively.

We are using Azure Media Services to perform the transcoding.
Potential solutions are:

1. Use Azure Media Services / Azure Blob functionality.  [`FetchAttributesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.fetchattributesasync?view=azure-dotnet) doesn't contain codec information.. Hanven't found any other applicable mehod.
2. I am only concerned with `if == H.264 || if != H.265`. Use knowledge of the [`.Mov` Container](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/QuickTime_container#Known_FOURCCs) and download using `CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream()`
   or intercept the `iFormFile` Stream on upload and read the specific bytes(FOURCCs?) to make determination.

Holding the entire video in server memory is not an option.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using our service to transcode the MOV files, then we do support both H.264 and H.265 as input codecs. Does this solve your problem? And you can see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-input-metadata-schema for information on how to determine input codecs *after* the transcode completes, if you needed to. Thanks.

Comment: I only want to transcode files that need it.  So will only want to transcode `H.265` to `H.264`.  IOW, need to know before transcoding what type it is.  My fallback is to trust the Client to tell Server.  Also won't be using the streaming.

Comment: I think you are saying you want to check the video codec either before upload or on the server and from your description it sounds like you are actually streaming the video, rather than uploading it? You are then transcoding, if necessary, as you stream to enable you to stream it out - correct?

Comment: @Mick - Streaming can have multiple meanings.  The upload is technically a stream, I never hold the entire Video in memory, it goes straight to Blob Storage.  I am not streaming it on download.  After upload, if its not playable by chrome, I need to transcode it basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to decide whether or not to encode the source MOV, based on video codec, then you could implement the following:

1. User uploads the MOV file
2. Upon upload complete, Event Grid topic on Azure Storage fires an event
3. An Azure Function is the event handler/subscriber receiving the event
4. That Function then (a) Determines that this is a new video upload, (b) Creates a SAS URL for the video, (c) Runs ffprobe to determine the video codec, (d) If H.265 then submits an encoding Task

Note: if you don't want to use ffprobe, then you can submit a Thumbnail task on the source video. This will be a low cost job, and the output Asset will contain the input metadata XML file which can be parsed to determine the codec. In my comment above, I've provided a link to the schema for this XML file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [@Anil Murching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6331794/anil-murching) - ffprobe I assumed would load the entire blob into memory.  But the info about Thumbnail task is exactly what I need.  Will verify and mark as answer.  Thx!